# I need help exporting the values of a variable that is in a function

Tags: javascript, function, module, var

I have a code that aims to create several news on the HTML page. I am consuming an API that is returning the news.

In the current code, I have three functions: one to display the news on the screen `exibirNoticias()`, the second one to show the news in the aside `exibirNoticiasAside()`, and a third `openNoticias()` one that I'm having difficulties with. Its purpose is to track the clicked link and return the data-attribute containing the ID of the clicked news. I managed to implement this part successfully, but I'm having trouble getting this ID assigned to the variable `idNoticias`, which I declared outside the function without any value. I would like to export this variable to another script where I will display the news on the screen.

```
const noticiaSection = document.querySelector('.noticias__container');
    const asideSection = document.querySelector('.aside__post');
    var noticias = [];
    var idNoticia;
    fetch("https://api-kwi5.onrender.com/v1/api/noticias")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
    noticias = data.response;
    console.log(noticias);
    exibirNoticias(noticias);
    exibirNoticiasAside(noticias);
    openNoticias(noticias);
    })
    .catch((erro) => {
    console.log(erro)
    function exibirNoticias(noticias) {   
    noticias.forEach(elemento => {
        console.log(elemento.id);
        noticiaSection.innerHTML += `<div class="noticias__cards">
        <a href="/pages/noticias-postagem.html" data-id="${elemento.id}" class="img__noticias--container">
          <img src="data:image/png;base64,${elemento.file}" alt="Dentistas fazendo um tratamento bucal em uma paciente" class="img__noticias--cards">
        </a>
        <div class="noticias__cards--conteudo">
          <a href="/pages/noticias-postagem.html" data-id="${elemento.id}" class="cards__conteudo--containertitulo">
            <h3 class="cards__conteudo--titulo">${elemento.titulo}</h3>
          </a>
          <div class="cards__conteudo--info">
            <ul class="conteudo__info--lista">
              <li class="conteudo__info--item">Maio 29,2023</li>
              <li class="conteudo__info--item">Notícia</li>
              <li class="conteudo__info--item">Dr.Wesley</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="conteudo__info--texto">${elemento.descricao}</p>
          </div>
          <a href="/pages/noticias-postagem.html" data-id="${elemento.id}"  class="noticias__btn">Continue lendo</a>
        </div>`


    });
 
}

function openNoticias(noticias) {
  const btnNoticiasId = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]');
  // console.log(idNoticia)
  btnNoticiasId.forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);
      idNoticia = e.getAttribute('data-id');
      console.log(idNoticia);
      })});
  }); 
  
}

function exibirNoticiasAside(noticias) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        asideSection.innerHTML += `
        <div class="aside__post--card">
              <a href="" data-id="${noticias[i].id}" class="post__card--imgcontainer">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,${noticias[i].file}" alt="Dentista mostrando 4 mitos dos implante dentarios" class="post__card--img">
              </a>
              <span class="post__card--data">Junho 7,2023</span>
              <a href="#" data-id="${noticias[i].id}" class="post__card--titulo">${noticias[i].titulo}</a>
            </div>
        `
    }
}
```

I have tried exporting the variable `idNoticias`, but it goes as undefined. I'm looking for a way to export this variable with the new value I assigned to it in the function `openNoticia()`. However, it always goes as undefined. I attempted to use `console.log()` on `idNoticia` inside the `openNoticia()` function after assigning a value to it, and the variable in `console.log` shows that it has the new value, but when I export it, it still goes as undefined.

I need help to solve this issue because I must be able to export this variable with the value of the ID found in the `openNoticas()` function. Then, I want to export this variable to another script where I will search the API for a news item with a similar ID. Once I retrieve the data from the API, I will display the news on the screen.